# Running Nodejs on Managed Hosting server but the website goes down after some interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, putty, production-environment

I am facing this problem from last two weeks.
I am accessing and running server from puTTy terminal. Earlier i was facing problem that when i close my puTTy terminal the website showed 503 error, despite of using 'nohup' command.

> nohup npm start --production &

Then i tried using 'Screen' , now if i close my terminal , the website is still live but after some hours (20-24) the Screen is dead and the server is also down.
Please give me a solution to run node.js app in production without the hassle of this 503 error

Comment: An error could terminate the process, so check your logs.

Comment: you should take care of error handling

Comment: If it's about managing and keeping node-processes alive on a remote host, I like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io). `npm install pm2 -g` and `pm2 start script.js`. It'll also restart your process if goes down by default.  `pm2 ls` to list your processes, `pm2 logs` to show logs and that's pretty much all you'll ever need (but pm2 can do a lot of other cool stuff too). Of course, you should still fix the problem if your app errors out.

Comment: If you really want to get rid of server setup efforts, you should try a managed server hosting like Heroku. https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: @damitj07 heroku is a bit expensive and i want database to be unlimited, thats why i opted managed hosting server. Its pretty cheap :)